# other font-size after <br> in a Heading <h1>

Tags: html, css, font-size, html-heading

Ok here is the thing. I need 2 different font sizes in my <h1> heading.
The text after the <br> need to be larger than the text before.

```
<h1>Welcome text from<br>Name</h1>
```

So I tried it with

```
h1 {
  color: #c3c2c2;
  font-size: 35px;
}

h1 br:after {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Wrap Name in a `span`, then `h1 span {...}`

Comment: choose on of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11987145/1057730 http://stackoverflow.com/a/11987196/1057730

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want or cannot change the markup, you could use the [`:first-line`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-line) selector from CSS3. Something like this:

```
 <h1>Welcome text from <br/> Name</h1> 

 h1 { 
   color: #c3c2c2; 
   font-size: 50px; 
 } 

 h1:first-line { 
   font-size: 35px; 
 }
```

[According to Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) the compatablity is quite okay, especially if you use the one-colon syntax over the `::first-line` syntax (all good browsers support it, and IE from 5.5 and up as well).

See a [jssfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vNJs/) for a working demo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to edit the markup, wrap "name" in a span and target the span with your selector.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it:

HTML:

```
<h2>Heading<br><span class="name">Name</span></h2>
```

CSS:

```
.name {
    font-size:200%;
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghWKm/

However, its more common to keep the heading to one line and put the subheading as a new element (`h3` for example) underneath it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
`<h1>`Welcome text from`<span class="abc">Name</span></h1>
```

instead of

`<h1>`Welcome text from`<br>`Name`</h1>`

And give style to .abc

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap each side in a span and then set the sizes differently there, this will also mean that you do not need the br.

```
<h1>Welcome text from<span class="size2">Name</span></h1>

h1 {
  color: #c3c2c2;
  font-size: 35px;
}

h1 .size2 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```